# Jssor lazy load for iframes

Tags: iframe, lazy-loading, jssor

I'm using Jssor to build a slideshow with iframes. In each Iframe there's a video in it with autoplay (built through Hype). To make it, I build the slideshow on my space in jssor, then export it in jquery, then replace in the code the images divs with iframes. My issue: how to make lazy loading works with iframes ? Since to make it work with images I would need to replace scr by scr2, but with iframes ?...
Thank you for the help. If I can't make it work, all the Iframes with video load at the same time and it slows the show... There you can see the slideshow: http://www.expo.martincoiffier.com/belle_ile-CINEMAGRAPHS-jquery/

Comment: Wow, great job!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can leave `src` attribute to empty for iframe elements in the second slide, and  listen to `$JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK` event, and then set `src` attribute after the slide comes.

```
jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK,function(slideIndex,fromIndex) {
    if(slideIndex == 1) {  //the second slide parks at the view
        //set src attribute for iframe elements in the second slide
    }
});
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-api.html